Do I need to go through immigration for my CDG transit with separate tickets on different airlines?
I have a flight from South Africa to Paris CDG (Turkish airlines) and I need to fly to the US the same day. I'm considering flying either 3 hours or 6 hours later from CDG to the US with a separate ticket (different airline - United), which seems to be in the same terminal (both terminal 1).
Will I have to go through immigration and security in Paris, or can I just act as if I had a connecting flight with the same company and stay in the gate area? I'll take the 3-hour connection if I don't need to go through security.
I won't have a checked bag and I'm a US citizen.

You should call the airline with which you have the ticket for the second leg. Some airports and airlines have a transfer desk, where you can present yourself and get a boarding pass and be checked in. Some airlines will let you check in online, so that's an option too. But given that you're flying to the USA, it's possible that the airlines would like for you to present yourself at the check-in counter.

3 hours seems pretty tight to me, allowing for eg passing through security check on arrival and the gate closure time  of your onbound flight https://www.united.com/en/us/fly/travel/airport/airport-process.html

Have you  ever heard of a flight being delayed by six hours?  I suppose you probably have; it happens pretty frequently.  If your flight from South Africa to Istanbul is delayed sufficiently, you might arrive in Paris a day later than planned.  You should be prepared for the possibility of missing your departure from CDG.  Will you be able to change your ticket after missing the flight?  If not, are you prepared to purchase a new ticket to the US at same-day or next-day prices?

As you travel on different airlines, the first airline will assume you will enter France and for that you need a visitor visa (if you need a visa for the Schengen area) whatever the situation with transferring in CDG.
I have seen now you are an US citizen and as such do not need a visa, but might still have to exit the secure area.
3 hours is a short time for a self connection and I would suggest at least the 6 hour one but better an overnight stop. I would go for 27 or 32 hours to be on the safe side.
